# Enable syntax highlight between custom tags

Tags: syntax-highlighting

When I work with ruby .erb files, vim correctly detect javascript blocks and highlights them accordingly:

```
... colored html ...
<script>
  ... colored javascript ...
</script>
... more colored html
```

I have defined blocks in my erb template that puts it's content in `<script>` tags, but vim doesn't know about it and i end up with this:

```
... colored html ...
<% content_for :tail_script do %>
  ... javascript is not detected and is colored as html ...
<% end %>
```

How can I add custom tag detection to enable javascript syntax highlighting?

Comment: I can't find it right now but I am pretty sure we have _at least_ one duplicate question about this kind of nested syntax highlighting problem on the site. (And I think the duplicate don't have a satisfying answer)

Comment: ['nested syntax highlighting'](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7445/nested-highlighting)  was the keyword i was looking for. :) thank you.

Comment: Cool! So did the duplicate answered your question? Can we close yours as a duplicate? :)